# extjs getselectedcell() but not using Ext.grid.CellSelectionModel

Tags: extjs

I hv an editorGridPanel and it's selmodel=new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel(), but I want to get the selected column by using getSelectedCell, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Here is working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/qxpfJ/1/

[image]

```
function cellRenderer(value, column, record, row, col){
    return Ext.String.format('<span key="{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}">{4}</span>',
       record.data.id, column.column.dataIndex, row, col, value);
}

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Countries',
    selType : 'cellmodel',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                fields:['id', 'cName'],
                data:{'items':[ { id: 1, cName: 'Australia' },
                                { id: 2, cName:'Germany' },
                                { id: 3, cName:'Russia' },
                                { id: 4, cName:'United States' }]},
                proxy: {
                    type: 'memory',
                    reader: { type: 'json', root: 'items' }
                }
            }),
    columns: [{ text: 'id',  dataIndex: 'id', renderer: cellRenderer },
              { text: 'Country', dataIndex: 'cName', flex: 1, renderer: cellRenderer }],
    listeners:{
        selectionchange: function( me, selected, eOpts ){
            var sel = Ext.query('.x-grid-cell-selected span');
            if(sel[0]){
                var data = sel[0].getAttribute('key').split('_');
                container.update( Ext.String.format(
                    'id={0};<br/>column="{1}";<br/>rowIndex={2};<br/>colIndex={3};',
                    data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]));
            }
        }
    }
});

var container = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', { 
    renderTo: Ext.getBody() 
});
```

**EDIT**

And here is same sample, but for **checkboxmodel**: http://jsfiddle.net/qxpfJ/2/

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Countries',
    selType : 'checkboxmodel',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                fields:['id', 'cName'],
                data:{'items':[ { id: 1, cName: 'Australia' },
                                { id: 2, cName:'Germany' },
                                { id: 3, cName:'Russia' },
                                { id: 4, cName:'United States' }]},
                proxy: {
                    type: 'memory',
                    reader: { type: 'json', root: 'items' }
                }
            }),
    columns: [{ text: 'id',  dataIndex: 'id' },
              { text: 'Country', dataIndex: 'cName', flex: 1 }],
    listeners:{
        cellclick: function( me, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts ){
            container.update( Ext.String.format(
            'id={0};<br/>rowIndex={1};<br/>cellIndex={2};',
             record.data.id, rowIndex, cellIndex)); 
        }
    }
});

var container = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', { 
    renderTo: Ext.getBody() 
});
```

Comment: But my seltype must be 'checkboxmodel'

Comment: I had changed my answer